# State the domain of $f^{-1}$

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x+5}$$
$$x \geq -2.5$$
State the domain of $f^{-1}$
\begin{align}
\ x & = \sqrt{2y+5} \\
\ \Rightarrow f^{-1}(x) & = \frac{x^2-5}{2} \\ 
\end{align}
The Mark Scheme  says that the domain is $x\geq0$

Is the Mark Scheme wrong or am I?
Let $x=-3$
$$\frac{(-3)^2-5}{2}=2$$
I thought the domain was the values of $x$ you can put into the function without getting an "error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you're dealing with inverse function of $f(x)$, say $g(x)$, your range of $f(x)$ typically will be your domain for $g(x)$.

In your case, your $f(x)= \sqrt{2x+5}$, and hence, has a range that takes on values from $[0, \infty)$. This implies that, your domain for $f^{-1}(x) =g(x)$ is $[0, \infty).$

Comment: Why? It makes sense why $f(x)= \sqrt{2x+5}$ is restricted but not $f^{-1}$

Comment: It makes sense because $f(x)$ is a one-to-one function, you can show this using the horizontal line test. The definition for an inverse function for $f(x)$, is given by $f^{−1}(y)=x \iff  f(x)=y$. Now, say the domain for $f(x)$ is given by A. Precisely, by the preceding definition, each value of $y$ in the domain of $f^{−1}$ has exactly one $x$ in A.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Precalculus/Section_2.7-One-to-One%20Functions%20and%20Their%20Inverses/One-to-One%20Functions%20and%20Their%20Inverses.pdf

Comment: Does it have to be one-to-one because $f(x)= \sqrt{2x+5}$ is restricted? Are you essentially inversing the domain as well the function?

Answer (score 0):

any x in the domain must satisfy the equality 
$$x = \sqrt{2y + 5}$$
therefore $x\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

squaring $x=\sqrt{2y+5}$ you must have $x\ge 0$

Comment: $x^2=2y+5$ What am I missing?

Comment: You have missed the condition $x\ge 0$ because $\sqrt{2y+5}$ is a positive number.